# Cambiar de posicion un td de una tabla html

Tags: javascript, jquery

hola quisiera que alguien me pudiera ayudar necesito que al cargar la pagina cada td que esta en la tabla cambie de posición de manera aleatoria con todo su contenido por ejemplo el td numero 1  cambiara a la posición donde se encuentra el td numero 4

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>hola1</td>
        <td>hola2</td>
        <td>hola3</td>
        <td>hola4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Podremos ayudarte, pero muéstranos que tienes hecho hasta ahora...  Puedes leer [ask] para editar y mejorar la redacción además de aumentar la calidad de tu pregunta... Hazlo para evitar puntuaciones negativas o reportes...

Answer (score 1):

Podrias crear un string con todos los campos externos de la tabla, luego con los que quieres que aparezcan aleatorios, crear un array de ellos, desordenar el array aleatoriamente, y añadir cada elemento del array al primer string, luego hacer un **innerHTML** del string para concatenar la tabla aleatoria a la web.
Por ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">   


    function creaTabla(){
        //Principio tabla
        var stringTabla = "<table><tbody><tr>";

        //Array de elementos que tendrán que salir aleatoriamente
        var array = ["<td>hola1</td>","<td>hola2</td>","<td>hola4</td>","<td>hola3</td>"];

        //Desordenamos el array aleatoriamente:
        array =array.sort(function(){return Math.random()-0.5});


        //Una vez desordenado, tenemos que ir añadiendo cada elemento al string:
        for(var i = 0; i<array.length;i++){
            stringTabla+=array[i];
        }

        //Añadimos el final de la tabla
        stringTabla += "</tr></tbody></table>";

        //Añadimos el resultado a la web.
        document.getElementById("idTabla").innerHTML = stringTabla;

    }

  </script>
</head>
<body onload="creaTabla()">
    <div id="idTabla"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

El resultado sería una tabla nueva con los campos aleatoriamente cada vez que se cargue la página, por ejemplo:

**1º Carga:**

`hola2 hola1 hola4 hola3`

**2º Carga:**

`hola4 hola3 hola1 hola2`

**3º Carga:**

`hola3 hola1 hola2 hola4`